# refresh XWPFDocument changes

Tags: java, apache-poi, xwpf

I need remove cover page from document

```
XWPFDocument document = ...;

if(document.getBodyElements().get(0) instanceof XWPFSDT) {
    document.removeBodyElement(0);
}
```

When debugging `document` the `XWPFSDT` element is correctly removed but on output cover page is still here.

Is there some way to update/refresh document xml, even if changes are happens from low level, how can we refresh docs to keep it uptodate

Comment: Did you write the resulting `document` object back to a file ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Until `apache poi` version `3.17`, the [XWPFDocument.removeBodyElement](https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/poi/tags/REL_3_17_FINAL/src/ooxml/java/org/apache/poi/xwpf/usermodel/XWPFDocument.java?view=markup#l875) removes only `BodyElementType.TABLE` or `BodyElementType.PARAGRAPH` properly. It lacks [CTBody.removeSdt](http://atetric.com/atetric/javadoc/org.apache.poi/ooxml-schemas/1.1/org/openxmlformats/schemas/wordprocessingml/x2006/main/CTBody.html#removeSdt-int-).

So we must do the low level stuff our self:

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.*;

public class WordRemoveCoverPage {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument(new FileInputStream("WordDocumentWithCoverPage.docx"));

  if(document.getBodyElements().get(0) instanceof XWPFSDT) {
   System.out.println(document.removeBodyElement(0)); // true == success, but low level <w:sdt> is not removed from the XML
   document.getDocument().getBody().removeSdt(0);
  }

  document.write(new FileOutputStream("WordDocumentWithoutCoverPage.docx"));

  document.close();
 }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Axel Richter, you confirm I can only remove this page I can’t get paragraphs from  XWPFSDT object? Because sometimes I don’t want remove it juste get paragraphs and pply some logics on it and XWPDSDT.getBody().getParagrahps() seems null

Comment: @istiti: See my comments in your new question about this.